# How to use specific node version for yarn setup in AWS deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devops, chef-recipe, aws-opsworks

I have used yarn and webpacker for react setup in existing rails app. However I am getting setup failed in AWS deployment with following error.

```
Webpacker requires Node.js >= 6.0.0 and you are using 0.10.48
```

I have added cookbook receipe for Yarn. On each deployment it is looking through cookbook receipe.
How can I use specific node verion on yarn receipe?

Link to yarn receipe:
https://gist.github.com/RORingBBK/8ea8d2fdf9905645d8b0f8af22b2735b

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set your Node version by overwriting the appropriate attribute.

If you [create a custom cookbook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-installingcustom-enable.html) for your project, and create a `opsworks_nodejs/attributes/customize.rb` file. In there set the following

```
normal[:opsworks_nodejs][:version] = '6.0.0'
```

This has worked for me in the past (a couple years ago) - there's been some shift since then but it still should be the same...

Comment: I have changed on customize.rb as mentioned above, but that did not work as I am getting same nodejs version error for webpacker. Is there anything I need to add on yarn receipe default.rb file that I have attached link to?